# How to make foreach %doparalell% execute all iterations?

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel, snow

I am setting up a foreach loop with %dopar%. The function inside should be executed n times. However no matter what the function is the function is executed only 6 times. There are no errors.  How do I make foreach execute all iterations?

I tried changing the number inside of makePSOCKcluster() and results are the same.  Currently I am running **makePSOCKcluster(nworkers)** with **nworkers = 7** ( parallel::detectCores() returns 8 ). I was originally running a complex function inside my loop but I tried substituting the function for something simple like **sqrt()** and I get the same result. I am working on a mac:
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.2

Using package versions:
doParallel_1.0.11 iterators_1.0.10  foreach_1.4.4

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(foreach) )
suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(doParallel) )

nworkers <- parallel::detectCores() -1 
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(nworkers)
registerDoParallel(cl)

epkgs = c("lubridate","dplyr","tidyr","doParallel","foreach", "Rcpp")
efuns = ls(globalenv())

foreach( i= 1:31, packages = epkgs, .export = efuns) %dopar% { sqrt(i)}
```

The result I get is :

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1.414214

[[3]]
[1] 1.732051

[[4]]
[1] 2

[[5]]
[1] 2.236068

[[6]]
[1] 2.44949
```

While the functions should have returned 31 elements.

Comment: This is a typo, you need to use `.packages` with a dot. Otherwise it is considered as a variable you want to iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update I was missing a "." in front of packages so it was assuming that was an iterator. 6 packages 6 results.